# php-google-spreadsheet-client

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

Установил через composer библиотеку **php-google-spreadsheet-client** для работы с google таблицами. При попытке обратится к таблице получаю ошибку. Таблица с таким именем на диске есть.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Google\Spreadsheet\Exception\SpreadsheetNotFoundException' in 
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\GoogleDocs\vendor\asimlqt\php-google-spreadsheet-client
>   \src\Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetFeed.php:100  Stack trace: #0
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\GoogleDocs\index.php(39): 
>   Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('test') #1 {main}
>   thrown in 
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\GoogleDocs\vendor\asimlqt\php-google-spreadsheet-client
>   \src\Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetFeed.php on line 100

**Код PHP:**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;
use Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService;

$clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$clientEmail = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$pathToP12File = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.p12';

function getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile($clientId, $clientEmail, $pathToP12File) {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($clientId);

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $clientEmail,
        array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'),
        file_get_contents($pathToP12File)
    );

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }

    $service_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
    return $service_token->access_token;
}
$accessToken = getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile($clientId, $clientEmail,  $pathToP12File);

$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);


$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle('test');
```